# Trying to identify a story about a man with memory loss

Tags: story-identification

He wakes up in a strange house, with a gravel drive that goes nowhere, there are books with titles but blank pages, and there is a garage with a minotaur-like beast in the basement.

He tries to leave by boat, but ends up back at the house, a day or so later, the river seems to go in a circle.

He runs up the hills lining the valley and ends up touching the dome of the sky, peels back a layer of covering, and there is nothing out there.

I remember that the book was an anthology of a 19 year-old author, pre-1989. in 
English - paperback

Thanks!

Comment: Was the author male or female?

Comment: Male - as far as I recall

Comment: By "anthology of a 19-year-old author" you mean that it was a single-author collection? There are very few sf writers who have had a paperback short-story collection published by age 19. That should narrow the search down quite a bit, assuming 19 wasn't a typo.

Comment: 19 was what I remember reading on the back cover. I have searched many times before.

Comment: Robert Silverberg started writing at age 12 and was published by 13. Maybe a very old collection of his work?